# No ads appearing

Tags: adsense

Website: picnoon.com

When I log in from my desktop computer, I can only see ads in the header and footer section.But there are ads among the pictures. I can see ads between images when I log in from my mobile device.

And appear on some content, while others do not

Ads appear on: https://picnoon.com/post/2119261807408075902_1768407110
Content without ads: https://picnoon.com/post/2137632165987843085_1259903168

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with front-end but when you inspect you find 3 errors and those just happen to be the ads you were trying to place in the middle of the images if I am correct. 
It is pretty clear that it needs at least 250px to be able to show. And available width is 248.
[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBkzd.png)
Hope that helped even a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've missed the error messages. So why do you think ads don't appear on this link?  Doesn't show an ad-related error in Console

https://picnoon.com/post/2137632165987843085_1259903168